# Apply DNS Zone changes Plesk API

Tags: php, dns, plesk

I have a question related to Plesk API.

I managed to create subdomains, edit DNS zone via PHP, but when I go into Plesk, I get the following error message to the subdomain that was affected by the change of DNS:

> Warning: The DNS zone was modified. If you would like to apply DNS template changes to this zone, either click the 'Apply DNS Template Changes' button on this page or choose the 'Apply the changes to all zones' option in Server Administration Panel > Tools & Settings > DNS Template Settings > Apply DNS Template Changes.

Now, I read through the API Docs and I found a way of doing this, but I am not sure what the 'used-ip' tag is. Is it the IP of my Plesk hosting?

Here it is what I found in the docs.

```
<packet>
<dns>
<sync-with-template>
<filter>
  <used-ip>123.123.123.123</used-ip>   
</filter>
</sync-with-template>
</dns>
</packet>
```

See the 'used-ip' value? What is it?

Thanks,
Cristian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I managed to find an answer. The used-ip value is the value of the subdomain's hosting.

As from the Docs: It specifies the IP address of the DNS zone.